ReferenceError: document is not defined in Jest while testing React component in a Next.js projec
I'm trying to write a unit test for a React component in my Next.js project using Jest and React Testing Library. However, I'm encountering the following error when running the test:
`Testing Home Component › renders a heading
The error below may be caused by using the wrong test environment, see https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string.
Consider using the "jsdom" test environment.

ReferenceError: document is not defined`

Here is my test code:
Home.test.tsx
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import Home from "./Home"; // Adjust based on your file structure

describe("Testing Home Component", () => {
  it("renders a heading", () => {
    render(<Home />);
    const text = screen.getByText(/Home/i);
    expect(text).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});

Home.tsx
'use client'

import React from 'react'

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      Home
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home


I tried running a Jest test for a React component in a Next.js project using @testing-library/react. The test renders the Home component and checks if a heading containing the text "Home" is present in the document.
Here is the test I used:
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import Home from "./Home"; // Adjust based on your file structure

describe("Testing Home Component", () => {
  it("renders a heading", () => {
    render(<Home />);
    const text = screen.getByText(/Home/i);
    expect(text).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});


I expected the test to pass successfully, meaning the Home component would render, and the heading with the text "Home" would be found in the document. However, I encountered the following error:
ReferenceError: document is not defined

It seems to be related to https://www.npmjs.com/package/nwsapi. Please check https://github.com/dperini/nwsapi/issues/135

Thanks! I just downgraded the Next.js version, and now it's working fine.

I'm also having the same issue. I tried to freeze old versions of my dependencies (including next) and run tests again - same error.
I concur with Alberto's opinion - that's not the issue with codebase, but with external dependency. But I'm unable to find which one exactly. Jest and all related packages to it were released at least a few days ago, so they should not break everything just today.
Perhaps it's the issue with the Next. At first I thought it was Next's custom transformer for tests written in Typescript, which relies on SWC compiler:
next/dist/build/swc/jest-transformer.js
However, it was not updated for a few month and seems to work fine. Also I use Next 14, so it's not even latest major release. So I checked these libraries also

JSDom, which creates a DOM abstraction for these tests was last
published 2 month ago.
@testing-library/jest-dom was last published a months ago
@testing-library/react was published 3 months ago
Jest itself was published 4 month ago

My guess a dependency of any of these libraries is the issue. For now I just disabled React tests to preserve CI pipelines

If you rebuild your package-lock.json, everything is fine now. The offending package dependency (nwsapi) has been updated already.

The issue seems to be resolved now, with nwsapi updated release to 2.2.16

This is the link to the official issue with a possible temp workaround: forcing nwsapi to 2.2.13 version
https://github.com/dperini/nwsapi/issues/135

Tested on NWSAPI 2.2.13 and everything is back to green.
